# My MUI select not working with my array data with map function in react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have this simple Select in which i am trying to show the data from the array.

but it shows empty select

In the console it shows the data but in select it won't show.

```
[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement enabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled.
Write.jsx:105 data 1
Write.jsx:105 data2 
Write.jsx:105 data3
```

```
let categories = ["data 1", "data2 ", "data3"];

<FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">
              Category
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
              id="demo-simple-select-helper"
              value=""
              label="Category"
              onChange={handleCategoryChange}>
              {/* <MenuItem value="">
                <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem> */}
              {categories.map((key, value) => {
                console.log(value);
                <MenuItem key={key} value={value}>
                  {value}
                </MenuItem>;
              })}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
```

Comment: I destructured it now , but it still won't work. Tried, tried that the first time, like ```(item)``` and then get ```item.key``` and ```item.value```. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the return and change the order of the paramaters you pass like this: `value, key`

```
{categories.map((value, key) => {
    console.log(value);
    return (
      <MenuItem key={key} value={value}>
            {value}
      </MenuItem>
    );
 })}`
```

and if you don't want the `console.log()`, you can return it directly like this:

```
{categories.map((value, key) => (
     <MenuItem key={key} value={value}>
         {value}
     </MenuItem>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, return was missing. jsx was not rendering like that. when added return , it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.map()` [has the following syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
map((element) => { /* … */ })
map((element, index) => { /* … */ })
map((element, index, array) => { /* … */ })
```

When you write `categories.map((key, value)`. The key is the string name of the category and value is actually the index.

Maybe try this:

```
{categories.map((s, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={index} value={s}>
      {s}
    </MenuItem>
))}
```

And also, the arrow syntax for the function works like this for returning the element: `(s, index) => (<Element>...</Element>)`. When you write `{}` you need a return.

Working sandox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-73743681-d3t4dr

Comment: I did try this, but the data is not at all showing. I checked the syntax again and again , but it is not showing the data at all.

Comment: @ShivShankarPrasad Check out the sandbox I linked. You also had an extra `;` after the closing MenuItem.

Comment: It was missing a return, when i added the return, it worked like a charm.